# Time function stored in browser local storage is not deleting after initiation window.localStorage.removeItem()

Tags: html, css, reactjs, node.js

so I am building an app that monitors when food in a restaurant display expires. so a user enters the food into the application when the food is passed from the kitchen to the display, then the timer starts reading according to how long the food is meant to display, 1 hour 2 hours, or more.

I store the time in local storage with a specific name tied to a specific food type. But when the food expires i wrote a code that removes the food name from local storage but this is not working.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import customFetch from "../utility/customFetch";

function TimeFunction({ shelfLife, productId, id, status, expireIn }) {
  // let updatedProductAdded = [];

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { mutate: updateAddedProduct, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (updatedProductAdded) => {
      console.log(updatedProductAdded);
      return customFetch.patch(`/updateAddedProductOne`, updatedProductAdded);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["addedProducts"] });
      console.log("updated");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
  if (isLoading) {
    return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  }

  if (window.localStorage.getItem(productId)) {
    console.log("e day");
    const storageTime = window.localStorage.getItem(productId);
    const [time, setTime] = useState(storageTime);
    // let xyz = [];
    useEffect(() => {
      let timerBoss = setTimeout(() => {
        setTime(time - 1000);
      }, 1000);
      if (window.localStorage.getItem(productId) == 0) {
        console.log(productId);
        let updatedProduct = {
          id: id,
          productId: productId,
          status: 1,
          timeProductExpired: expireIn,
        };
        // xyz.push(updatedProduct);
        updateAddedProduct(updatedProduct);
        window.localStorage.setItem(productId, 0);
        window.localStorage.removeItem(productId);
        clearTimeout(timerBoss);
      }
    }, [time]);

    window.localStorage.setItem(productId, time);
    const getFormattedTime = (milliseconds) => {
      var days = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = String(
        Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
      ).padStart(2, 0);
      var minutes = String(Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))).padStart(
        2,
        0
      );
      var seconds = String(Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)).padStart(2, 0);
      const item = `${hours}: ${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
      // if (window.localStorage.getItem(productId) == 0) {
      //   clearTimeout(timerBoss);
      // }
      return `${hours}: ${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
    };

    return <h5>{getFormattedTime(time)}</h5>;
  } else {
    const hourly = shelfLife * 60 * 1000; //the time in hours can be passed in through props
    const [time, setTime] = useState(hourly);
    window.localStorage.setItem(productId, time);
    useEffect(() => {
      let timerBoss = setTimeout(() => {
        setTime(time - 1000);
      }, 1000);
      if (window.localStorage.getItem(productId) == 0) {
        console.log(`timer ${productId} down`);
        let updatedProduct = {
          id: id,
          productId: productId,
          status: 1,
          timeProductExpired: expireIn,
        };
        updateAddedProduct(updatedProduct);
        window.localStorage.setItem(productId, 0);
        window.localStorage.removeItem(productId);
        clearTimeout(timerBoss);
      }
    }, [time]);
    const getFormattedTime = (milliseconds) => {
      var days = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = String(
        Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
      ).padStart(2, 0);
      var minutes = String(Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))).padStart(
        2,
        0
      );
      var seconds = String(Math.floor((milliseconds % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)).padStart(2, 0);
      const item = `${hours}: ${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
      // if (window.localStorage.getItem(productId) == 0) {
      //   clearTimeout();
      // }
      return `${hours}: ${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
    };

    return <h5>{getFormattedTime(time)}</h5>;
  }
}

export default TimeFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call windows.localStorage, instead of that call localStorage.removeItem("item"); directly in your code. remove "windows" keyword.

```
localStorage.removeItem("item");
```

And also please Verify Item Key name.

```
localStorage.removeItem(productId);
```

Comment: true, but when i open the app in another browser, the timer starts all over again since the key is not stored in this browser.  Can i store the time in a DB and call? how will the structure or process be like?

Comment: you can try SQLite as an alternate DB solution.